# INSERT in order instead of UPDATE ... WHERE

Tags: postgresql

I have a database (I use PostgreSQL) with more than 25 million records. Now, I must create some new columns and I want to INSERT data into them instead of UPDATE ... WHERE ... Since I do not need WHERE condition because I will UPDATE data in order (eg. id ASC).

The reason I do that is because INSERT is faster than UPDATE (I tried with 50,000 records, INSERT just took about 10-15 seconds while UPDATE took few minutes)

So, is there anyway to INSERT in order instead UPDATE ... WHERE ...

Comment: If you are create rows you insert. If you are updating existing rows you update. Which one are you doing? If you are creating new columns it sounds like you need to update

Comment: Please post the UPDATE query that is executing slow.

Comment: I use this syntax to update 
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2,  column3 = value3,  column4 = value5
WHERE id = record_id;
I believe this the normal syntax. And I need to update 25 million records like this.